# How to add all records to database from a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, bulkinsert

I'm adding the records present in a datagridview into my database but only the data of the first record is being added - multiple times.

If there are five rows present then the data of 1st row is being added 5 times into database.

```
Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As String
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not dr.IsNewRow Then
            a = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            b = dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString
            c = dr.Cells(2).Value.ToString
            d = dr.Cells(3).Value.ToString
            connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\sample.accdb"
            connection.Open()
            sql = "INSERT INTO  sampleone(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES (@ID, @FN, @LN, @AGE)"
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Connection = connection
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = a
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FN", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = b
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AGE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = d

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()

        End If
```

Comment: Please show your code first so we can better assist you. Without any code we are not able to see where you may be going wrong.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it sounds like you have an unbound DataGridView. My suggestion would be to bind the DataGridView to a BindingSource that is bound to your DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
For i = 0 to datagridview.rowCount - 1
    QueryExecute($"INSERT INTO `YourTable` VALUES ('{datagridview.Item(0, i).Value}', '{datagridview.Item(1, i).Value}')", DatabaseConnection)
Next
```

Since I do not know how you are accessing your database, please input the query above into your code.

I have also assumed that your datagridview has 2 columns. If it has more, you can extrapolate the code inside.

I hope my answer has solved your problem

Comment: Any answer regarding sql queries should include the use of parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: you can try and integrate the parameters that you have tried to used in your code above in my code